# Updating a config file based on the presence of a specific string

Tags: bash, config

I want to be able to comment and uncomment lines which are "managed" using a bash script.

I am trying to write a script which will update all of the config lines which have the word #managed after them and remove the preceeding # if it exists.

The rest of the config file needs to be left unchanged. The config file looks like this:

**configFile.txt**

```
#config1=abc #managed
#config2=abc #managed
config3=abc #managed
config3=abc
```

This is the script I have created so far. It iterates the file, finds lines which contain "#managed" and detects if they are currently commented.

I need to then write this back to the file, how do I do that?

manage.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

STR='#managed'
if grep -q "$STR" <<< "$line"; then
  echo "debug - this is managed"

  firstLetter=${$line:0:1}
  if [ "$firstLetter" = "#" ]; then
    echo "Remove the initial # from this line"
  fi
fi

echo "$line"

done < configFile.txt
```

Comment: Only the leading `#` yes? Not the `#` from _managed_?

Comment: Sorry yes, the "tag" needs to stay regardless

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` one-liner should do the trick:

```
sed -i.orig '/#managed/s/^#//' configFile.txt
```

It deletes the `#` character at the beginning of the line if the line contains the string `#managed`.

---

I wouldn't do it in `bash` (because that would be slower than `sed` or `awk`, for instance), but if you want to stick with `bash`:

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = *'#managed'* && ${line:0:1} = '#' ]]; then
        line=${line:1}
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < configFile.txt > configFile.tmp
mv configFile.txt configFile.txt.orig && mv configFile.tmp configFile.txt
```

Comment: Add `-i` to write the result back to `configFile.txt` instead of standard output.

Comment: Thanks. Also spotted on MacOS you need an extra set of quotes, so: sed -i '' "/#managed/s/^#//" configFile.txt

Comment: @JonWinstanley The `-i` option requires an argument (an empty string is accepted as an argument) in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

With your approach using `grep` and `sed`.

```
str='#managed$'
file=ConfigFile.txt

grep -q "^#.*$str" "$file" && sed "/^#.*$str/s/^#//" "$file"
```

---

Looping through files ending in `*.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str='#managed$'

for file in *.txt; do
  grep -q "^#.*$str" "$file" &&
  sed "/^#.*$str/s/^#//" "$file"
done
```

---

- In place editing with `sed` requires the `-i` flag/option but that varies from different version of `sed`, the GNU version does not require an [-i.bak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281543/is-my-interpretation-of-sed-i-bak-x-d-some-file-correct) args, while the BSD version does.

---

On a `Mac`, `ed` should be installed by default, so just replace the `sed` part with.

```
printf '%s\n' "g/^#.*$str/s/^#//" ,p Q | ed -s "$file"
```

- Replace the `Q` with `w` to actually write back the changes to the file.
- Remove the `,p` if no output to `stdout` is needed/required.

---

On a side note, embedding `grep` and `sed` in a shell loop that reads line-by-line the contents of a text file is considered a bad practice from shell users/developers/coders. Say the file has 100k lines, then `grep` and `sed` would have to run 100k times too!

Comment: If i run the reverse: "sudo sed -i "" "/#managed/s/^/#/" configFile.txt" multiple times, I get two ## characters at the start, is it possible to only ever add one # ?

Comment: The reverse should be something like: `sed "/^[^#].*#managed/s/^/#/"`

Comment: That is: `^` start or beginning , the `[^#]` is a bracket expression and the `^` inside that bracket which is the first character, negates. Meaning anything but the character/string/pattern next to it. the `.*` is zero or more strings. Basically the pattern/regexp has `#managed` somewhere and it does not start with a `#`.